# Redirect to new product page instead of current product Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, url, third-party-module

Onclick custom button "**Register**" (present in product view page), we are trying 3 things:

1. Register user to site. (Working)
2. Create new product programtically. (Working)
3. Redirect to newly created product url (**Not Working** Instead, its redirecting to same Product's url)

---

```
public function createSimpleProductAndRedirect1Action()
{
    $originalProductId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $originalProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($originalProductId);

    if ($product = $this->_createit(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, true, $originalProduct)) {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $result['redirect'] = $product->getProductUrl();
            return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }
}

protected function _createit($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = '')
{
    $res = '';
    $login = '';
    $productId = '';

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    try {
        $errors = $this->_getCustomerErrors($customer);
        if (empty($errors)) {
            $res = $this->saveProduct($type, $doSave, $originalProduct, $newImagePath);
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');

            if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                return $res = $this->saveProduct($type, $doSave, $originalProduct, $newImagePath);
            }
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    }
}

public function saveProduct()
{
    // Product creation code
}
```

For "**Login**" . all 3 steps are working.

Comment: Have you tried with `$this->_redirectUrl($product->getProductUrl());`.

Comment: No,  comment  `$result['redirect'] = $product->getProductUrl();` and `return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));` and use `$this->_redirectUrl($product->getProductUrl());`

Comment: @SaravananDS in `Response tab` its directing to `new url`, but onclick button its keep on showing `loading symbol......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your line

```
$result['redirect'] = $product->getProductUrl();
```

With this one

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($product->getProductUrl());
```

Comment: tried with `$result['redirect'] =     Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($product->getProductUrl());` , still its redirecting to current page only.....

Comment: At which moment are you calling createSimpleProductAndRedirect1Action

Comment: i am submitting form `createSimpleProductAndRedirect1Action`  once i click on `submit` button.....

Comment: that 3rd part extension we were using, in that they used `location.reload();`  in code , changing this to `document.location = response.redirect;` worked for me.....